# joining specific parts of different csv files together in R

Tags: r, merge

I have been merging csv files using this function that I created long time ago:

```
mergeCSV=function(mypath) {
  filenames=list.files(path=mypath, full.names=TRUE)
  datalist= lapply(filenames, function (x) read.csv(file=x, header=TRUE))
  Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y, all = TRUE), datalist)}
```

However, now I have some csv files that have two parts: the main part and extrainfo, as you can see in the following picture:
[image]

I would like to modify my function in such a way that it takes the extra info of each participant and paste it next to the main part. The intended output for each file would be like this:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Questions should be reproducible. Please don’t use images of data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. Paste your data into the question as a data frame object or use `dput(...your data...)` Check out stack overflow guidance [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a special `read_csv_spec` function that is able to process both your usual .csv files, as well .csv the files that have extra info:

```
library(tidyr)

read_csv_spec <- function(file) {
    
    data <- readr::read_csv(file)
    
    if (any(grepl("extraInfo", data))) {
        
        midline <- which(is.na(data[ , 1]))
        
        top <- head(data, midline - 1)
        bottom <- tail(data, nrow(data) - midline - 1)
        
        bottom_clean <- pivot_wider(bottom[ , 1:2], 
                                    names_from = names(data)[1],
                                    values_from = names(data)[2])
        
        data <- cbind(top, bottom_clean)
    }
    
    return(data)
}
```

The function reads in a csv file forcefully, and then parses it appropriately if it has `extraInfo` in it.

For example, if you have a file that looks like this (shorter version of what you posted):

[image]

Using our `read_csv_spec` function on it will return the following result:

```
read_csv_spec("file.csv")

#   rand   name whole right_pic distractor part participants group gender Age
# 1 0.38 Carmen     w      CF11       CF12 eyes           43     G female  19
# 2 0.38 Carmen     w      CF12       CF13 eyes           43     G female  19
```

The function also works on normal .csv files, so all you need to do now is replace `read.csv` with `read_csv_spec` in your `mergeCSV` function:

```
mergeCSV=function(mypath) {
  filenames=list.files(path=mypath, full.names=TRUE)
  datalist= lapply(filenames, function (x) read_csv_spec(file=x))
  Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y, all = TRUE), datalist)}
```